# Boundary: single form or plural form?

Tags: grammatical-number

I am not sure whether "boundary" should be used in single form or plural form. For example, should I say:

I developed this method to define A region's boundary 
OR 
I developed this method to define the boundaries of A region

?

Comment: Both are correct, with different implications. In the absence of constraints of context, you can use either.

Answer (score 4):

"Boundary" designates the entire curve which encloses A; "boundaries" designates the several portions of that curve which respectively constitute the boundary between A and B, between A and C, between A and D, and so forth. So it seems to me the question is Which is more appropriate to your method?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the nature of 'A region', but in some cases either *boundary* or *boundaries* can be used.